# Getting server response 405 when trying to read response body

Tags: java, web-services, response

I am trying to read the response body for a webservice request which is a POST method.

I have tried changing the method type to GET just to try even though it is a POST request it did not work. However, it does give me a response code '200' yet while trying to read the response body with a reader i get error '405'.

Could anyone please give me some guidance on this.
I need to read the entire response body and then save one item which is a dynamic alphanumeric string to another property file.

Thanks in advance.

`

```
try{
    URL url = new URL(myUrl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod(POST);
    conn.connect();
    int respCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    if(respCode != 200)
    {
        System.out.println("connection refused");
    }
    else{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(url.openStream());
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            inline = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(inline);
            sc.close();
        }
}catch(Exception e){
e.prinstackTrace();
}
```

`

Comment: Response Codes which are in the form of 4xx are client error codes. Normally, 405 would mean "Method Not Allowed" but I have seen them sometimes when the client is unable to understand the type of response as well. 

You should add headers - Content-Type and Accept in your request and then see the output. It might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks it helped !!

Comment: If you were able to solve your problem, let me know so I can put the comment as an answer itself and it can be useful to other people as well.

Comment: Yes, I added the headers and my request had no body so skipped the sending Params part and I did get the response. Thanks !

Comment: Great !! Added my comment as answer. Please accept to help others.

Comment: Why are you trying to POST with no post data?

Answer (score -1):

Response Codes which are in the form of 4xx are client error codes. Normally, 405 would mean "Method Not Allowed" but I have seen them sometimes when the client is unable to understand the type of response as well.

You should add headers - Content-Type and Accept in your request and then see the output.

It might solve your problem.

Comment: All HTTP response codes originate at the server. You have not seen what you claim: you have just misunderstood. Adding those headers won't solve anything. If you think otherwise you need to state *why*. Otherwise you are just engaging in cargo-cult programming,

Comment: Yes, all codes definitely originate at server side. As far as solution to problem is concerned, it's already mentioned by the user of the question that his problem was solved.